# Php-mysql connectivity

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to write a PHP program which should take input from user and match with data placed in MySQL.

I tried to write program using mysqli in php

`new mysqli($hostname,$user,$password,$db)`

This line does not establish a connection.

Then I changed some user privileges as described in
https://askubuntu.com/questions/766334/cant-login-as-mysql-user-root-from-normal-user-account-in-ubuntu-16-04

But even then my PHP code is not connecting with MySQL. What should I do for establishing this connection.

Should I need to change some root permissions ?

Comment: send us your error and well written code, please see how to establish and debug a connection   http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php

Comment: This has nothing to do with permissions at the OS level. You haven't given us enough code that you've tried or shown us the error that you are getting. Make sure you have error reporting enabled and edit your question to include more of your code and the exact error you are getting. (`ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);`)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
/* CONNECTION */
$database_connection = new StdClass();

/** MySQL hostname */
$database_connection->server = 'localhost';

/** MySQL database username */
$database_connection->username = 'username';

/** MySQL database password */
$database_connection->password = 'password';

/** The name of the database */
$database_connection->name = 'dbname';

/* ESTABLISHING THE CONNECTION */
$database = new mysqli($database_connection->server, $database_connection->username, $database_connection->password, $database_connection->name);


if($database->connect_error) {

    echo 'db error';
}
```